# Logstash coverting field names to all lowercase

Tags: python, mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm using Logstash to keep my MySql  database and ES in sync.
I want to keep field names in both databases to be same.
But logstash is converting some uppercase field names to lowercase.
How to config logstash, so that those uppercase field names remain same?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to configure your `jdbc` Logstash input with the [`lowercase_column_names`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-lowercase_column_names) setting which is true by default:

```
jdbc {
     ...
     lowercase_column_names => false
}
```